# .Net MVC4 updating database

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I am struggling to update a database. All i need to do is update a column called balance

In my controller i have this

```
     public void updateBalance(int account, double amount)
    {
        var accounnt = db.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(u => u.AccountNumber == account);

        if (accounnt == null)
        {

        }
        else
        {
           //   update the balance column in account table         
        }

    }
```

can some one please assist?

Comment: what is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have loaded your entity, you simply need to update its properties and call `SaveChanges` on your `DbContext`.

```
  if (accounnt == null)
    {

    }
    else
    {
       account.balance = 1000;
    }
  db.SaveChanges();
```